# Make sprite walk along an angle

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl

I am trying to make a sprite walk towards another sprite,

```
movement_angle = (atan2((y - target->y),(x - target->x)));

if(isWalkable(game,delta))
{
    y -= ((int)(movementspeed)*delta)*sin(((movement_angle)));
    x -= ((int)(movementspeed)*delta)*cos(((movement_angle)));
}
```

I am calculating the angle and adding the values to my x and y cords.
But the movement is not perfect, it does not really follow as I wish, takes weird turns and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what's going wrong from your code, but here are some things you could look at:

1. To get a vector from a point to `target` you'll need to subtract `target->x` by the point's `x` and `target->y` by the point's `y`
2. At least `movement_angle` needs to be a floating point number, though you'll likely want to use `doubles` for all your 3D geometry values
3. Why bother with trigonometric functions? You want to walk directly from point `x`, `y` to `target->x`, `target->y`, why not just use a vector, normalize it, and multiply by your `movementspeed` and `delta`?

Answer (score 0):

Well you are casting an algebraic result to an int. I think that may be causing your problem.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34494/how-do-you-make-bullets-move-at-an-angle-in-different-angles-using-delta

Comment: Removed the (int) and made the x and y to float, but didn't solve it.. :/

Comment: What is "isWalkable(game,delta)" doing?

Comment: Checking if the tile in front of the sprite is a wall.